# Please explain how this javaScript code removes all nodes

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop, removechild

### HTML

```
<ul id="myList">
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

I can't seem to understand how this `while` statement deletes all the nodes in the above list. Can someone please explain?

### JavaScript

```
while(myList.firstChild) {
    myList.removeChild(myList.firstChild)
};
```

Comment: It works this way, While loop will execute till `myList` has firstChild. And in the loop you are removing each of its firstChild so the next one becomes the firstchild. It continues until all are removed, when `myList.firstChild` becomes null it is `falsy` so it no longer runs the loop.

Comment: [The documentation on while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) is quite helpful. The loop removes – `removeChild` – the first child – `myList.firstChild` – of a node until there are no more first children (and hence no more children) of the node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read [***while***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<ul id="myList">
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

**js code**

```
while(myList.firstChild) // loop will run while myList has a firstChild
    {myList.removeChild(myList.firstChild)
};
```

Run time

```
1st time while loop run firstChild is <li>Item 1</li> --> code runs and remove it.
```

**Now HTML**

```
<ul id="myList">
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Run

```
2nd time while loop run firstChild is <li>Item 2</li> --> code runs and remove it.
```

**Now HTML**

```
<ul id="myList">
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Run

```
3rd time while loop run firstChild is <li>Item 3</li> --> code runs and remove it.
```

**Now HTML**

```
<ul id="myList">
   <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Run

```
4th time while loop run firstChild is <li>Item 4</li> --> code runs and remove it.
```

**Now HTML**

```
<ul id="myList">
</ul>
```

Run

js code will not run as there is no first child in `myList`. While loop condition fails.